# Image not showing in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I don't know why the images aren't showing in Django. Something to do with the media root?

**settings code**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')'
```

**models code**

```
from django.db import models
```

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

## Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):

```
## Post Properties
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
summary = models.CharField(max_length=255)
content = models.TextField()
published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img',default='media/placeholder.png')


class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s'% self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog.views.post', args=[self.slug])
```

I didn't add a url for the picture, could that be a problem?

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^post/(.*)', blogViews.post),
url(r'^about/$', blogViews.about),
url(r'^$', blogViews.index),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

**index.html code**

```
<img src="{{post.image}}">
<p> {{post.image}} </p>
```

**Views.py **

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts': posts})



def post(request, slug):
    return render_to_response('post.html', {
    'post': get_object_or_404(Post,slug=slug)
    }) 

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {})
```

In the website all that shows is a blank picture as well as the file name (either 'placeholder.png' which is the default or img/... which I uploaded through admin)

**Edit:**

This was marked as a duplicate, I saw that post and tried to change my code to reflect that code but it wasn't working. Figured it would be better to post my own.

Thanks in advance, first question on this site!

Comment: `<img src="{{post.image.url}}">`

Comment: did you added media url in the main urls.py ?

Comment: Have you defined anything to actually serve media files?

Comment: I didn't add anything to the urls file. I tried adding (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}) but all I received was an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<img src="{{post.image.url}}">
```

Also, add in your `urls.py`,

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] 

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

For learning more about serving static, refer the documentation [here...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Same error, I didn't add anything in the urls.py file. Would that affect this?

Comment: Not sure what happened. It showed all the default pictures but not the ones I manually uploaded.

Comment: Could you show your view for this template?

Comment: Updated in my question

Comment: Does post has more than one image?? also post the full models.py please?

Comment: No, each post only has one image. Some of the posts that were already created default to the media/placeholder.png picture show up. But the other ones do not.

Comment: Figured out the issue. I was under the impression that when you upload the image it automatically saves into your media folder. I saved/ uploaded the pictures from the media folder and now it works. Thanks for the help!